# Using Bind Function

Tags: data-binding, query-string

I need to Bind "JobRefNo" to the query string.Above binding gives an error.what is the correct way?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="MoreLinkButton" PostBackUrl="/real/Coordinator/Home.aspx?JobRefNo="'<%# Bind("JobRefNo") %>' runat="server">Go To Job...</asp:LinkButton>
```

Link Button is inside a DataList control.Error says
"Call to Bind must be assigned to a property of a control inside a template"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of an odd one there -- you've ended the PostBackUrl property and then started an unmatched binding: `aspx?JobRefNo="'<`

It would probably be better to compose your value in the model in the code behind and then eval the whole lot into the postback url:

Code behind:

```
public string JobRefPostback {
    get{return "/real/Coordinator/Home.aspx?JobRefNo="+JobRefNo;}
}
```

On page:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="MoreLinkButton" PostBackUrl='<%= JobRefPostback %>' runat="server">Go To Job...</asp:LinkButton>`

Hope that helps!